# Instead of versus after trigger for auto-update datetime column

Tags: sql-server, triggers, datatrigger

Suppose I have a table in which I have a datetime field (name it `updated_at`) to perform as a "timestamp" column (because in SQL Server the timestamp datatype doesn't exists as a datetime).

I have considered to use triggers to update the field, but I don't know which kind will work better:

- Use a `instead of update` trigger, and do the update inside trigger, but setting the `updated_at` value to `getdate()`. This is more difficult to code, but maybe will perform better because it will do a single update operation.
- Use a `after update` trigger, and do a second update to the modified row(s), to set the datetime value to `getdate()`. This could be a little bit easier to code, but implies doing two updates on the table.

Which will be the best approach, in terms of performance?

Comment: Just test both options and see for yourself. It's almost always quicker and easier to test something yourself than to wait for someone else to give a general answer that may not be applicable in your specific situation. SSMS and SQL Profiler can give you a lot of information about execution time and execution plans.